# CliBuilder: First option or second option

Tags: groovy

I defined the following CliBuilder options:

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import org.apache.commons.cli.Option

def cli = new CliBuilder()

cli.with {
   d(longOpt: 'database', 'database', args: 1, required: true)
   u(longOpt: 'user', 'user', args: 1, required: true)
   p(longOpt: 'password', 'password', args: 1, required: true)

   _(longOpt: 'doFoo', argName: 'foo param', args: 1, "make foo.")
   _(longOpt: 'doBar', 'do bar.')
}

def opt = cli.parse(args)

if (!opt) return 
if (opt.h) cli.usage()

println "Hooray"
```

Parameters d, u and p are defined as **required**. doFoo and doBar are **not** defined as required, but one of them **should be** defined at least, otherwise the program should fail / should execute method usage().

What is the best way to solve that? Is there a way to implement a kind of **OR** condition (doFoo or doBar)?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like the [API](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/util/CliBuilder.html) has anything specifically on point for an OR condition between arguments. You could try doing it yourself, something like this seems to work:

```
//same code above
def opt = cli.parse(args)
if(!(opt.getInner().options.find { it.longOpt == 'doFoo'} || opt.getInner().options.find { it.longOpt == 'doBar'})) {
   println "Must include doFoo or doBar!"
   cli.usage()
   return
 }
 //same code below
```

It would output the same usage message plus a more specific message about including doFoo or doBar.